# Accented characters not showing correctly in org-mode HTML export

Tags: org-mode

I have following basic HTML setup for org-mode

```
#+TITLE: Blog
#+AUTHOR: Burak Kaan Çopur

#+HTML_DOCTYPE: html5
```

and this gives me following head in generated HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- 2018-02-22 Thu 22:11 -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Blog</title>
<meta name="generator" content="Org mode">
<meta name="author" content="Burak Kaan Çopur">
```

You can see that charset is set to `UTF-8` and language of the document is set to `en`. When I write HTML manually, I use these settings and my name which includes a `Ç` shows just fine. But org exported HTML files are not able to display them. What might be the problem here?

Here is what causing me the problem. I opened one of the `.org` files in Notepad++ and said `convert to UTF-8`. When I republish through emacs, this time it works but if I reopen the same file in emacs then it is messed up again. I have following in my configuration so I was thinking my emacs buffers are all encoded in `UTF-8`

```
;; UTF-8 as default encoding
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
```

So what might be the reason for emacs to not use `UTF-8` encoding?

Comment: Can't confirm this on Emacs-26.0.1 and org-mode 9.1.3.

Comment: Could a script or CSS file loaded later in the document mess with the encoding?

Comment: I opened the .org file in Notepad++ and said convert to UTF-8. Then when I published, it worked fine. So I am guessing, emacs is not saving the file in UTF-8 encoding. I will update the question.

Comment: Anyone want to explain the downvote?

Comment: @Dan For using Notepad++ to change the encoding instead of using Emacs! ;-)  In earnest the problem is not related to org-mode! It's a mishandling of Emacs, the user doesn't know how to handle the file coding system, or how the "wrong" coding system appeared at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem. I had this on my `.emacs` file.

```
;; UTF-8 as default encoding
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

I thought these makes every buffer encoded in `utf-8`. In reality, if one of your files have a different encoding for some reason, emacs will use that encoding. But If you open a new file, emacs will use `utf-8` by default. So my `.org` files were encoded differently, I don't know how that happened. To change them, I used

```
C-x RET c
```

This prompts you to chose an encoding, I went for `utf-8`. Then asks for a command to execute with this encoding. I said `C-x C-s` to save using `utf-8`. That solved my problem.